# For given operations on a large set of data, is there a way to determine if the data can be decomposed into mapreduce operations?

Tags: java, math, mapreduce, mathematical-optimization

We do stats and such on large sets of data.  Right now it is all done on one machine.  We're studying the feasibility of moving to a map-reduce paradigm where we decompose the data into subsets, run some operations on that, then combine the results.

Is there any sort of mathematical test that can be applied to a set of operations to determine if the data they operate on can be decomposed?

Or maybe a list somewhere saying what can and cannot be decomposed?

For instance, I didn't think there was a way to decompose standard deviation, but there is...

edit: added tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this paper: http://www.janinebennett.org/index_files/ParallelStatisticsAlgorithms.pdf . They have algorithms for many common statistical problems, and there is open source code available.

Answer (score 1):

Variance, as well as the mean can be calculated online (in a single pass), see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#On-line_algorithm). There's also a parallel algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel computing is best suited to problem which are "embarrassingly parallel" i.e., there is no dependency between any two tasks.
Please check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel

Also, In cases where the operations are commutative or associative, MapReduce programs can easily be optimized for better performance.